# Data Access Permissions

Tags: architecture

I'm looking to find most efficient way of handling access permissions for users based on the data.
For example, I have business structure like: Clusters > Companies > Departments > Users.
Each level can have some resources (Clusters having addresses, phones, whatever...), Companies also, Departments also...

What i'd like to accomplish is that each User can access data only from his Cluster/Company/Department...

What is the most efficient way for it? or am I forced to do checks like CheckIfUserInCompany(userId, companyId)?

Thanks in advance!

PS.
using ASP MVC but asking a general, non-language-specific thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

A hierachy where each node is allowed everything he/she is allowed and everything that all children are allowed or a hierachy where each node is forbidden to do what is forbidden to him and all the parents.

Or roles. So everyone can have one or more roles and what you can do is the merge of all the roles you are in.

Comment: Thanks for your response! That sounds like a solution for case when for example DepartmentManagerRole needs to access Department info. But what I want to make sure is that DepartmentManagerRole can access only Department he is a part of and not any other. Likewise for all other resources. So, if anyone sends request for GetDepartmentDetails(departmentId) for departmentId he is not a part of > he gets Forbidden.